# How to plot same space between MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween and MainAxisAlignment.start?

Tags: flutter

Please refer to my code and Screen Shot below

Top two rows are build based on `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` widget and a bottom row is on `MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween`, respectively.

As you can see in Screen Shot,`MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween` have no spaces like spacebetween, and I understood this is default behaviour of `MainAxisAlignment`.

However, I want keep same spaces between the items in 5 items, even if it consists of less than 5 items(like two items shown in Screen shot).
Is there any good ideas to implement this ?
thanks for your helpful advise.

```
  final List<String> _icon = [
    "lock.png",
    "cheer.png",
    "map.png",
    "stake.png",
    "sushi.png",
    "lock.png",
    "cheer.png",
    "map.png",
    "stake.png",
    "sushi.png",
    "cheer.png",
    "map.png"
  ];
var iconChunks = _icon.slices(5).toList();

Column(
    children: iconChunks.map((e) => Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10.0),
        child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: e.length ==5 ? MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween :MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: e.map((s) => selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: s)
            ).toList(),
        ),
    ))
    .toList()
),
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using GridViewBuilder? Maybe this will help.

```
GridView.builder(
    shrinkWrap: true,
    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
    gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
      crossAxisCount: 5,
      mainAxisSpacing: 10,
      crossAxisSpacing: 10,
    ),
    itemCount: _icon.length,
    itemBuilder: ((context, index) => selectIcon(id: 1, iconPass: 
       _icon[index])),
  ),
```

Comment: Thanks for useful advise and sorry for late reply. My PC has broken and please give me few more days to recover and try this code.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily maintain same height and weight by `Gridview`. `Column` `Spacebetween` and `start` are totally different concept.As you are don't know about list, it may be increase or decrease better you should have to use `Gridview`.

```
 return Container(
                  // padding: const EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
                  child: GridView.builder(
                    physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: lengthoflist,
                      childAspectRatio: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width /
                          (MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.4),
                      mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                    ),
                    itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      Category category = snapshot.data[index];
                      return Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            child: Image.network(
                              category.image,
                              fit: BoxFit.cover,
                            ),
                            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              border: Border.all(width: 1.0),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                              top: 8.0,
                            ),
                            child: Text(
                              category.name,
                              textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                            ),
                          )
                        ],
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                );
```

Comment: Thanks for useful advise and sorry for late reply. My PC has broken and please give me few more days to recover and try this code.